# I need to call the functions by directly by giving function base address to PC with parameters......how?

Tags: arm

```
    void fun1(int x)
{
    display(x);
    display(x+1);
    display(2*x);
}

void fun2(int x)
{
    display(x*3);
    display(x+3);
    display(x-1);
}
void fun3(int x)
{
    display(x+2);
    display(x+5);
}
.
.
.
.
function_ptr[]={fun1,fun2,fun3,.......fun20};
int st=0;// to indicate the function count
int main()
{
    GLCD_init(); 

   //comment here


}
```

**comment is as**

> after GLCD initialisation i  have to call above functions.So, now my problem is...take a condition..if st=3 then i have to execute fun2,fun3,fun4,fun5 ..with condition statements i can..but with the help of st value i have call those functions directly..for that i am using assembly language so that we can give our function address to PC directly...here i am facing a problem with passing parameters..once we made a call to function by giving the base address of that perticular function to PC...how can i pass the parameters to those functions with along with the direct call...

Answer (score 1):

This depends completely on your system: some system pass the parameters register only, some in stack, some mix (e.g. only small or first values in regs).

See as reference  [Arm Procedure Call Standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/index.html)

If you are unsure how your system handle it, just dissassemble a procedure call to one of your functions, to see how it is done.